# Random Key Fetch In Coherence Cache

Tags: caching, oracle-coherence

I have a coherence cache which is access by 30 nodes.
Is there any method available ,which can give a random key?
Same key should not pull by other node.

Answer (score 0):

Use an entry processor (e.g. using its own member id as the key to execute the processor against) that goes to the server and asks it to generate a key, which would then be associated with that same key (using key association ... see Coherence JavaDoc). Then the server can generate unique keys that no one else will accidentally get.